# Residue Calculation Using given Conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

Assume $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a punctured domain (a is removed), and that $f(z)$ has a pole of order n greater than or equal to $1$.

Need To Compute residue at $z=a$ of $f'(z)/f(z)$

How to look forward for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z - a)^n}$$ where $g$ is analytic in the domain with $g(a) \neq 0$. Then

$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} - \frac{n}{z - a}.\tag{*}$$

Since $g(a) \neq 0$ and both $g$ and $g'$ are analytic at $z = a$, $g'(z)/g(z)$ is analytic at $z = a$. So the residue of $g'(z)/g(z)$ at $z = a$ is $0$. Since the resiude of $1/(z - a)$ at $z = a$ is $1$, it follows from $(*)$ that the residue of $f'(z)/f(z)$ at $z = a$ is $-n$.